# Why aren't these two equal?

Tags: scheme, racket

I was preparing for a test and I noticed this question:

```
Define an object x so that (eq? (car x) (cdr x)) returns #t
```

I initially thought that it would be pretty simple. `cdr x` is a list and `car x` is a single element, so my guess would've been make the first element in x be a list equal to the tail of x. So I came up with

```
(define x (list (list 1) 1))
```

Calling `car x` in DrRacket results in `(list 1)` and so does `cdr x`, but when I try to call `(eq? (car x) (cdr x))` the result is #f.

What exactly am I missing? Also what would the correct answer be?

Comment: `(eq? (list 1) (list 1)) => #f`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The thing that we can get the `car` and `cdr` of is not a *list*. It is a *pair*.

Pairs are created with the use of `cons`, e.g.:

```lisp
(define val (list 1))

(define val-pair (cons val val))
```

`(list (list 1) 1)`, on the other hand, is equivalent to `(cons (list 1) (list 1))`, where  `list` is called *twice*, each time returning a new, separate object in memory, though holding equal values. But `eq?` returns true only for the *same* memory object.

So while your thinking was sound, value-wise, what was actually compared here is not values but the *sameness*, as in "pointer equality" for memory objects, kind of.

Answer (score 4):

To use your example of using `(list 1)`:

```lisp
(define x
  (let ([tail (list 1)])
    (cons tail tail)))
```

An even simpler example:

```lisp
(define x '(()))    ; same as: (define x (cons (list) (list)))
```

This relies on the fact that there's only one empty list object (that is, while `(eq? (list 1) (list 1))` is always false, `(eq? (list) (list))` is always true).

---

On a related note (though somewhat over the top as far as your test goes), did you know you can also make an object `x` such that `(car x)` and `(cdr x)` refer to the same object as `x`?

```lisp
(define x (call-with-input-string "#0=(#0# . #0#)" read))
```

:-P

Answer (score 4):

The question is why

```
(define x (list (list 1) 1))
(eq? (car x) (cdr x))
```

gives the result `#f`.

First let's use `cons` instead of `list`.

```
(list 1)    is the same as  (cons 1 '())
(list a b)  is the same as  (cons a (cons b '())
```

Your example becomes:

```
(define x (cons (cons 1 '()) 
                (cons 1 '()))
(eq? (car x) (cdr x))
```

Since we have the expression `(cons 1 '())` twice above let's add an index (just so we can refer to the expressions.

```
(define x (cons (cons_1 1 '()) 
                (cons_2 1 '()))
(eq? (car x) (cdr x))
```

This shows that

```
(car x) returns the result of (cons_1 1 '())
(cdr x) returns the result of (cons_2 1 '())
```

A call `(cons a b)` will allocate a small data structure in memory that (roughly) looks like this:

```
<tag-for-pairs>  <pointer-to-the-value-a> <pointer-to-the-value-b>
```

This means that the calls `(cons_1 1 '())` and `(cons_2 1 '())` will allocate two pairs each pair will have its own location (address) in memory.

A call `(eq? x y)` will only compare the location (address) of the two objects `x` and `y`. This implied that even though the contents of two pairs are equal, the comparison `(eq? (cons_1 1 '()) (cons_2 1 '()))` will return false.